# How to rename a folder name with a shell script?

Tags: macos, shell

I have several folders that starts with a name and then a same phrase like this:

Bridget__taxaFound

Paul__taxaFound

I want to mantain just the name of this folders and eliminate the part "__taxaFound" do you have any suggestion?
I'm working with Mac shell and i dont have rename command of perl.
Thank you a lot to everyone

Andy

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for dir in *__taxaFound; do mv "$dir" "${dir%__taxaFound}"; done
```

Note that if `foo__taxaFound` exists as well as `foo`, this will simply move `foo__taxaFound` into the directory `foo`.  If `foo` is an extant file, this will generate an error.  YMMV.  Please understand what this command is doing before you execute it.